# Cloud Functions for Firebase FCM reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

error

> ReferenceError: functions is not defined
>       at Object. (C:\Users\CROWDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_9612Si4u8URDRCrr\index.js:5:21)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at C:\Users\crowderia\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
>       at Object. (C:\Users\crowderia\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:32:3)

index.js file like below

```
'use strict'
const funnctions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {
  const user_id = event.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
  cosole.log('User id is : ', user_id);
  if (!event.data.val()) {
    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
  }
  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
  return deviceToken.then(result => {
    const token_id = result.val();
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Friend Request",
        body: "You've received a new Friend Request",
        icon: "default",

      }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
      console.log('this is the notification feature');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: delete the comma after the icon: "default"

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo right in the first line

> const funnctions = require('firebase-functions');

functions, not funnctions :) so that this line

> functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id...

would work

Answer (score -1):

`cosole.log('User id is : ', user_id);` change it to `console.log('User id is : ', user_id);` and funnctions to functions.